# Advertising Identifier for devices lower than iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, udid

It seems that we cannot use `[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier` anymore. The Advertising Identifier is supposed to be used. But the Advertising Identifier is available only since iOS 6.0.

How can I uniquely identify a device lower than iOS 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the unique identifier is deprecated. For this i have a solution.Please go through the below link and i believe this is the replacement of apple UDID.

https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID#usage

http://www.secureudid.org

Answer (score 0):

On the first time the app is launched, create a UUID with `CFUUIDCreate`, convert it to a string with `CFUUIDCreateString`, and then save it to a file in the app's cache directory. On subsequent launches of the app, use the UUID saved to the file rather than creating a new on.

Comment: NSUserDefaults might be simpler to use for saving a string than writing it out to a file and reading it back.

Comment: If the user have re-installed the app, is this string still unique? I wanner help the user recover his data saved before, score, coins, things already paid, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry for that the user's data were saved on the server with [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier before. The user may not be able to get his played data back via [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier.