# iTunes App Submission Invalid binary issues

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store-connect

Non-public API usage:

Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.
If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed.

Kindly help me how to i avoid his problem.

Regards
John

Comment: Are you using the `uniqueIdentifier` method of UIDevice? If so, you may wish to use `identifierForVendor` instead. The error describes the issue pretty well -- I'd read over it again.

Comment: Iam created application using phonegap based  application.

Comment: I uploaded version1.0 to itunes sucessfully but now apple will not accept my binary

Comment: You may want to take a look at the property `[identifierForVendor]`(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49) of `[UIDevice]`(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class.

Comment: Then the last part may be especially applicable (if you don't think you're using `uniqueIdentifier` anywhere in your code): "note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app" especially if you're using an older version, or a plugin which hasn't been updated recently.

Answer (score 7):

> Apps are **not permitted to access the *UDID*** and must not use the ***uniqueIdentifier*** method of ***UIDevice***. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the ***Vendor*** or ***Advertising identifiers*** introduced in iOS 6

Theres your answer.

> "*Starting May 1, the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6*"

[Source](http://www.adexchanger.com/mobile/apple-sets-cut-off-for-udid-apps/)

Apple now block any App which accesses the `uniqueIdentifier` property of `UIDevice`. Replace any occurrence with the [Vendor or Advertising](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) identifiers or use [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID).

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
```

A few StackOverflow questions which may be of help:

- [Advertising Identifier for devices lower than iOS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858310/advertising-identifier-for-devices-lower-than-ios-6-0)
- [iOS6 UDID - What advantages does identifierForVendor have over identifierForAdvertising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve)
- [The advertisingIdentifier and identifierForVendor return "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605257/the-advertisingidentifier-and-identifierforvendor-return-00000000-0000-0000-000)

If you haven't used `uniqueIdentifier` yourself, then it will be an SDK Library calling it. Normally from an ad network such as Mobclix, AdMob or Smaato. All the popular ad networks have updated SDK's which remove `uniqueIdentifier`. Check their websites for the latest SDK.

**Update**

Just seen in the comments you're using PhoneGap, guessing you haven't updated to the latest version.

- [Apple have started rejecting UDID access now (PhoneGap)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/HRVgtO8a14A)
- [Re: [PhoneGap] Uuids in ios 5 (PhoneGap)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/IztwpBOlOqY)

Make sure your using the latest version (2.7.0) from http://phonegap.com/download/ (Released 30 Apr 2013)

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue and Apple gave me some tips to find out the Places that use "uniqueIdentifier" API call. Even in a binary lib.

> "While you may have removed access and usage of UDIDs from your app,
>   the invalid binary message indicates that your app uses or accesses
>   UDIDs. Please check your source code for any occurrence of the
>   "uniqueIdentifier" method; this is the method that returns a device's
>   UDID.
>
> Additionally, if you are linking an external framework, such as an
>   advertising library, these third party libraries may be accessing and
>   using UDIDs. We encourage you to update your libraries to the most
>   recent versions and use the "nm" tool to determine if the libraries
>   are calling this method.
>
> For more information on the "nm" tool, please see the manual page for
>   the "nm" tool in Xcode Tools:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html
>
> Additionally, if you do not have access to the libraries's source, you
>   may be able to search the compiled binary using "strings" or "otool"
>   command line tools. The "strings" tool can output a list of the
>   methods that the library calls and "otool -ov" will output the
>   Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These
>   techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code
>   resides."

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Ishara, are you able to solved this problem ? I am not  too Good in shall script. String command and otool. Please let me know if you can any help me. Thanks

Comment: in the root folder of your xCode project, do `find . -name "*.a" -print` to find the `.a` libraries. For each `<library>` produced, do `strings <library> | grep unique` to see if the method call is present. I didn't find `otool -ov <library>` useful - indeed, it crashed on one library.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method to create a Unique Identifier.

Is this now not allowed. It was a month ago when release a previous version of my app.

```
- (NSString *)uuid
{
    CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef);
    CFRelease(uuidRef);
    return [(NSString *)uuidStringRef autorelease];
}
```

What else can I use to create a unique identifier.

Cheers

Shane