# Phone Gap iPhone App itunes connect error “invalid binary”

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store-connect

I have created a phoneGap app for iphone and successfully deployed it device.
Now i am trying to upload the app to app store using xcode 4.5
Successfully validated.
Successfully Distributed.
itunes connect app status-- app received
after 3sec app status-- invalid binary
I am using phone gap 1.2.0, xcode 4.5, target ios version 6.0, Distribution provisional profile.

I have received email followup from apple

Non-public API usage:
Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.

If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed.
If you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's nine-digit Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above APIs were incorrectly flagged, toappreview@apple.com. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information page.

Somebody please help.

Comment: I have post answer from apple here

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449182/itunes-app-submission-invalid-binary-issues/16514820#16514820



Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Apple Changed their policy on using the UDID. Which was included by default in earlier version of Phonegap API on IOS. If you upgrade to the newer versions you will find the code no longer uses the UDID and will pass App store.

Looks like from version 1.8 onwards is the change. 
Latest version of phonegap is 2.7 so it would be good to update anyways,